# Shortcode displaying shortcode and not content

Tags: wordpress

Im using "insert pages" plugin for wordpress that allows me to insert pages and posts into other pages and posts from the backend. My problem being that when i i use "insert pages" plugin in my news section and then visit the site it shows the shortcode instead of the content. This seems to be a problem only when making a "post". If i use the plugin to display a page within another page it works fine (shows the content not the shortcode).

Any idea what could be the cause of this problem?

Cheers,
Emil

Update

```
// Shortcode hook: Replace the [insert ...] shortcode with the inserted page's content
    function insertPages_handleShortcode_insert( $atts, $content = null ) {
        global $wp_query, $post, $wp_current_filter;
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
                    'page' => '0',
                    'display' => 'all',
                ), $atts ) );

        // Validation checks.
        if ( $page === '0' ) {
            return $content;
        }

        // Trying to embed same page in itself.
        if ( $page == $post->ID || $page == $post->post_name ) {
            return $content;
        }

        // Don't allow inserted pages to be added to the_content more than once (prevent infinite loops).
        $done = false;
        foreach ( $wp_current_filter as $filter ) {
            if ( 'the_content' == $filter ) {
                if ( $done ) {
                    return $content;
                } else {
                    $done = true;
                }
            }
        }

        // Get page object from slug or id
        $temp_query = clone $wp_query; // we're starting a new loop within the main loop, so save the main query
        $temp_post = $wp_query->get_queried_object(); // see: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_Example_2

        // Convert slugs to page IDs to standardize query_posts() lookup below.
        if ( ! is_numeric( $page ) ) {
            $page_object = get_page_by_path( $page, OBJECT, get_post_types() );
            $page = $page_object ? $page_object->ID : $page;
        }

        if ( is_numeric( $page ) ) {
            $args = array(
                'p' => intval( $page ),
                'post_type' => get_post_types(),
            );
        } else {
            $args = array(
                'name' => esc_attr( $page ),
                'post_type' => get_post_types(),
            );
        }

        query_posts( $args );

        // Start our new Loop
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            ob_start(); // Start output buffering so we can save the output to string

            // Show either the title, link, content, everything, or everything via a custom template
            // Note: if the sharing_display filter exists, it means Jetpack is installed and Sharing is enabled;
            // This plugin conflicts with Sharing, because Sharing assumes the_content and the_excerpt filters
            // are only getting called once. The fix here is to disable processing of filters on the_content in
            // the inserted page. @see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content#Alternative_Usage
            switch ( $display ) {
            case "title":
                the_post(); ?>
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <?php break;
            case "link":
                the_post(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <?php break;
            case "excerpt":
                the_post(); ?>
                <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                <?php if ( has_filter( 'the_content', 'sharing_display' ) ) echo get_the_excerpt(); else the_excerpt(); ?>
                <?php break;
            case "excerpt-only":
                the_post(); ?>
                <?php if ( has_filter( 'the_content', 'sharing_display' ) ) echo get_the_excerpt(); else the_excerpt(); ?>
                <?php break;
            case "content":
                the_post(); ?>
                <?php if ( has_filter( 'the_content', 'sharing_display' ) ) echo get_the_content(); else the_content(); ?>
                <?php break;
            case "all":
                the_post(); ?>
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <?php if ( has_filter( 'the_content', 'sharing_display' ) ) echo get_the_content(); else the_content(); ?>
                <?php the_meta(); ?>
                <?php break;
            default: // display is either invalid, or contains a template file to use
                $template = locate_template( $display );
                if ( strlen( $template ) > 0 ) {
                    include $template; // execute the template code
                } else { // Couldn't find template, so fall back to printing a link to the page.
                    the_post(); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><?php
                }
                break;
            }

            $content = ob_get_contents(); // Save off output buffer
            ob_end_clean(); // End output buffering
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        $wp_query = clone $temp_query; // Restore main Loop's wp_query
        $post = $temp_post;

        $content = "<div data-post-id='$page' id='insertPages_Content'>$content</div>";
        return $content;
        //return do_shortcode($content); // careful: watch for infinite loops with nested inserts
    }
```

Comment: If you are a developer then check the plugin that hows its rendor the data and apply `do_shortcode("[shortcode]");` into the coding, OR raise a support ticket to the plugin author.

Comment: Hi thanks, how would i go about finding the shortcode name? When i install a fresh wordpress site it works in posts but not at this one I'm working with that has a lot of plugins.

Comment: there should be a hook with `add_shortcode` with the name of the shortcode in any file, you have to navigate it.

Comment: Thank you for your patience,
Found this in the insert-pages.php

function insertPages_init() {
   add_shortcode( 'insert', array( $this, 'insertPages_handleShortcode_insert' ) );
   
  }
Is this where i should add the do_shortcode? as such
do_shortcode('insert', array( $this, 'insertPages_handleShortcode_insert' ));

Comment: insert-pages.php is a class, and `insert` shortcode handled by `insertPages_handleShortcode_insert` method. You have to check this method in the same file.

Comment: Updated the main post, it was quite the huge method for this. Any ideas? Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is could be work for you.

```
while ( have_posts() ) {
        ob_start(); // Start output buffering so we can save the output to string

        // Show either the title, link, content, everything, or everything via a custom template
        // Note: if the sharing_display filter exists, it means Jetpack is installed and Sharing is enabled;
        // This plugin conflicts with Sharing, because Sharing assumes the_content and the_excerpt filters
        // are only getting called once. The fix here is to disable processing of filters on the_content in
        // the inserted page. @see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content#Alternative_Usage
        switch ( $display ) {
        case "title":
            the_post(); ?>
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php break;
        case "link":
            the_post(); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <?php break;
        case "excerpt":
            the_post(); ?>
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <?php if ( has_filter( 'the_content', 'sharing_display' ) ) echo get_the_excerpt(); else the_excerpt(); ?>
            <?php break;
        case "excerpt-only":
            the_post(); ?>
            <?php if ( has_filter( 'the_content', 'sharing_display' ) ) echo get_the_excerpt(); else the_excerpt(); ?>
            <?php break;
        case "content":
            the_post(); ?>
            <?php if ( has_filter( 'the_content', 'sharing_display' ) ) echo do_shortcode( get_the_content() ); else the_content(); ?>
            <?php break;
        case "all":
            the_post(); ?>
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php if ( has_filter( 'the_content', 'sharing_display' ) ) echo do_shortcode( get_the_content() ); else the_content(); ?>
            <?php the_meta(); ?>
            <?php break;
        default: // display is either invalid, or contains a template file to use
            $template = locate_template( $display );
            if ( strlen( $template ) > 0 ) {
                include $template; // execute the template code
            } else { // Couldn't find template, so fall back to printing a link to the page.
                the_post(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><?php
            }
            break;
        }
```

Comment: No success unfortunately. Thanks for all the help tough.